# customizing the auto generated grid view in asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm creating a column through ItemTemplate in my gridview, how can i adjust it to be my last column, unfortunately .net is making this column to be the first in grid view i want it to be the last column. The rest of the columns are automatically created by this code.

I mean

```
gridview1.datasource = myArrayList
gridview1.databind()
```

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the auto generation feature (AutoGenerateColumns="false") and supply the columns in the `<columns>` collection of the grid, or use LINQ:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>
{
   new MyClass { Name = "A", Value = 1, Key = 1 }
};

gridView1.datasource = list.Select(i => new
{
    i.Key,
    i.Name,
    i.Value
});
```

THe first option will be better on performance.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using Linq for my project. And I get the arraylist from the session in this manner.                                   ArrayList selectedComponentsForDownload = (ArrayList)Session["SelectedRowItems"];
            SoftwareDownloadsGridView.DataSource = selectedComponentsForDownload;
            SoftwareDownloadsGridView.DataBind(); And i want to add additional column at the end of created gridview using the item template but it always creates the column as first. How do i force it to be the last column ? Thank you in anticipation

Comment: @user653622 - You don't require linq, brain was just giving an example. In your case, mark AutoGenerateColumns = "false" in gridview properties. Then go to the Columns Property of GridView and refresh the schema if you have attached Datasource on the designer or else, add columns manually and populate the DataField property of the particular column with whatever field you want.

Comment: Yes explicitly define the columns.  Easiest, most performant way.